# passing access token to Jira using OAuth Authentication

Tags: oauth, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I am using OAuth authenication in Jira to test some methods in jira using JIRA Rest Java Client. I have got the access token using OAuth authenication that I need to pass on Jira URL. Here is all what I have got to get access token.

```
Token is 38ESi9IJW5u3vKDslPFtuV1ZtzDpr6zi
Token secret is cnDSL8oJyuoaQdRcFDwgHzLppSshQn9b
Retrieved request token. go to http://bmh1060149:8080/plugins/servlet/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=38ESi9IJW5u3vKDslPFtuV1ZtzDpr6zi
Access token is : 015CeJiH8cpI5R3OKpNco158kApq8YwV
```

Now I am passing that access token to Jira URL but I am getting an empty array. Please let me know where I am doing wrong or what changes do I need to incorporate into my code to make this thing work. Here is my code.

```
public void getAllIssueTypesUsingOAuth(JiraCQCredential jcqcred) {

        System.out.println("Inside getAllIssuetypeAssociatedToProject for JiraAdapterImpl");

        //String username = jcqcred.getUserName();
        //String password = jcqcred.getPassword();
        String jiraURL = jcqcred.getJiraUrl();
        if (!jiraURL.endsWith("/")) {
            jiraURL = jiraURL + "/";
        }
        try {
            String accessToken = JiraAdapterImpl.getAccessToken(); // This method is giving me access token
            URL url = new URL(jiraURL + "rest/api/2" + "/" + "issuetype?access_token=" + accessToken);
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
            httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConnection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            String issueTypes = sb.toString();
            System.out.println("Issuetype associated to project are\n" + issueTypes);
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(issueTypes);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String issueNames = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
                System.out.println(issueNames);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Its giving me an empty array like []

Answer (score 0):

Hi After searching the little bit I finally managed to a find the solution to the above problem. After getting the access token just pass that access token to the makeAuthenticatedRequest(url, accessToken) method that will give you the resultant data which you want to retrive. Here url is the url which you want to hit to get the resultant data.

```
private AtlassianOAuthClient getJiraOAuthClient() {

        final String baseURI = "http://bmh1060149:8080";
        final String consumerKey = "hardcoded-consumer";
        final String consumerPrivatekey = "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";

        AtlassianOAuthClient jiraoAuthClient = new AtlassianOAuthClient(consumerKey, consumerPrivatekey, baseURI, "");
        return jiraoAuthClient;
    }
```

Here is the code to get Access Token

```
private String getAccessToken() {

        AtlassianOAuthClient jiraoAuthClient = getJiraOAuthClient();
        TokenSecretVerifierHolder requestToken = jiraoAuthClient.getRequestToken();
        String authorizeUrl = jiraoAuthClient.getAuthorizeUrlForToken(requestToken.token);
        String token = requestToken.token;
        String tokenSecret = requestToken.secret;
        System.out.println("Token is " + requestToken.token);
        System.out.println("Token secret is " + requestToken.secret);
        System.out.println("Retrieved request token. go to " + authorizeUrl);

        String accessToken = jiraoAuthClient.swapRequestTokenForAccessToken(token, tokenSecret, "");
        System.out.println("Access token is : " + accessToken);
        return accessToken;
    }
```

This is the method you call to retrieve the data.

```
public void getAllCommentOfIssueUsingOAuth() {

        logger.info("Inside getAllCommentOfIssue for JiraAdapterImpl");

        AtlassianOAuthClient jiraoAuthClient = getJiraOAuthClient();
        String accessToken = getAccessToken();
        String url = "your Jira URL";
        String responseAsString = jiraoAuthClient.makeAuthenticatedRequest(url, accessToken);
        System.out.println(responseAsString);
    }
```

This will give you the resultant JSON data or XML data in resultantString.